# Wheel dynamics: reaction forces with ground

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

I am confused by part of a dynamic model in this paper: http://waset.org/publications/4405/real-time-control-of-a-two-wheeled-inverted-pendulum-mobile-robot see page 3, figure 5.

All forces labeled H and V are supposed to be reaction forces; I understand the pairs between the pendulum and the wheels, i.e. H(L) and V(L).

But I don't understand the horizontal reaction force between the wheel and the ground, H(TL). What does that force represent? Is it the forward force of the wheel? But I thought that should be the torque divided by the radius. Since V(TL) seems to be the normal of the ground on the wheel, I thought maybe it's a reaction force; or friction for all I know.

Thanks in advance for helping me clear the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be rolling friction. Even on the Moon, a wheeled vehicle will eventually come to rest because of friction at the axle and friction between the wheel and the ground.

The wheels on that vehicle are deformable. That means that the reaction force by the ground is not purely vertical. It has a horizontal component that resists the rolling motion of the wheel with respect to the ground.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know they were modeling a deformable wheel or what the implication would be. I have a follow-up question regarding the direction; it looks like H(TL) isn't opposing the direction of motion but is going the same way as the wheel would roll. Am I interpreting it incorrectly? Thanks again.

Comment: It looks to me like the paper is a bit sloppy. The left half of figure 5 is inconsistent with the right half, there are terms and variables that aren't defined, explained, or described by an equation. The grammar is terrible. If this was peer reviewed, the review was not very good.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Do you have any recommended resources where I could learn about the rolling friction caused by deformable wheels? Cheers.